# Iterating 2 elements in a *ngfor iteration of custom interface array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this exported interface

```
export interface MemberInfo {
  name: string
  surname: string
  email: string
}
```

and declared a MemberInfo[] inside my component like this

```
export class NetworkComponent implements OnInit {

  member_email!: string
  memberInfo!: MemberInfo[]

  constructor(private friendService: FriendService,
              private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // get member_email stored in local storage
    this.member_email = this.tokenStorage.getEmail()

    // get list of friends
    this.friendService.getFriends(this.member_email).subscribe(
      (response: MemberInfo[]) => {
        this.memberInfo = response
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

When the network component is loaded the friends information of said user are stored in memberInfo and I want to show them in my respective html file in a grid view, where 2 friends are shown per row. This is my html file

```
<ng-container class="container" style="--bs-columns: 3"
              *ngFor="let info of memberInfo; let i=index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"  >
      <div class="grid_text">
        <b> {{info.name}} </b>
        <b> {{info.surname}} | </b>
        <b> {{info.email}}  </b>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="grid_text">
        <b> {{info[i+1].name}} </b>
        <b> {{info[i+1].surname}} | </b>
        <b> {{info[i+1].email}}  </b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

I've searched online and found that when using ngFor I can access the next iteration value like in c for example but for some reason in my case it is not working and I get this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'MemberInfo'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'MemberInfo'.
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Info is a single member though..? And you’re already looping through all memberInfo objects. The error makes complete sense here. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe you meant to do memberInfo[i +1].name..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `memberInfo[i+1]` instead of `info[I+1]`.

As the error says, `info` is an object of type `MemberInfo`, it's not an array.

*Note that you'll have to handle duplicate items with your current solution. There are many ways to handle it (code, CSS...) but this is out of scope of this question.*

Comment: You're absolutely right, I don't know how I could've missed that, thank you